# Convert JSON into JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, json

I get response from server:

```
{'data':['29/10/2009','13/04/2009','19/10/2009','07/04/2009','20/05/2009','27/02/2010',
'20/04/2009','16/06/2009','15/12/2009','22/06/2009','21/09/2009','28/07/2009',
'19/01/2009','14/05/2010','30/03/2009','06/04/2009','21/01/2010','10/03/2009',
'17/09/2009','09/04/2009','27/10/2009'.....]}
```

I want to get this date array and put it into JS array:

```
                success: function(response){    
                intObj = response.responseText;
                for(var i in intObj) {
                    console.log(i);
                    if(intObj.hasOwnProperty(i) /*&& !isNaN(+i)*/) {

                        dateArray[+i] = intObj[i];
                    }
                }
            }
```

But get result in my array:

```
["\r", "\n", "\r", "\n", "\r", "\n", "\r", "\n", "\r", "\n", "\r", "\n", "\r", "\n",
"\r", "\n", "\r", "\n", "\r", "\n", "{", "'", "d", "a", "t", "a", "'", ":", "[", "'", 
"2", "9", "/", "1", "0", "/", "2", "0", "0", "9", "'", ",", "'", "1", "3", "/", "0", 
"4", "/", "2", "0", "0", "9", "'", ",", "'", "1", "9", "/", "1", "0", "/", "2", "0", 
"0", "9", "'", ",", "'", "0", "7", "/", "0", "4", "/", "2", "0", "0", "9"...]
```

How to put into array only dates? Like this `'29/10/2009','13/04/2009','19/10/2009','07/04/2009']`.

Comment: That isn't JSON.  (JSON must use double-quotes)

Comment: @SLaks: but firefox says that its JSON. Its wrong?

Comment: What do you mean that Firefox "says" it's JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) . I believe you need to use the `responseText` property , which returns the response as a string.

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
var dataArray = jsonObject.data;
```

Comment: I get error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'`

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse the string as JSON:

```
var result = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
```

You can then get the array directly:

```
var array = result.data;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Response is an object

```
var array = response.data;
```

### Reponse is a string

Convert it to object:

```
var response = JSON.parse(response);
```

Comment: If the response comes from ajax call be sure that you make `response = response.responseText`

Comment: `myarray = response.responseText.data;` not help too. Same result.

Comment: Please paste the content of response here.

Comment: Whats its mean? You want to see screenshoot of response?

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the result.

```
var arrayOfDates = JSON.parse(response.responseText).data;
```

Comment: Sorry, never heard about it.

Answer (score -1):

try to use

```
var intObj = eval("(" + response + ");");
for (var i in intObj.data) {
        console.log(i);
        if(intObj.hasOwnProperty(i) /*&& !isNaN(+i)*/) {
             dateArray[+i] = intObj[i];
        }
}
```